# Oracle over-indexed tables

Tags: oracle, index

I am trying to improve performance of a view in Oracle 11g, the view joins 11 tables, the 3 biggest tables in the query are 40, 27, 19 milions of rows. I found that each of these big tables has more then 80 different indexes. Besides that I suspect the database server has a lack of memory. 
I know that many indexes can harm performance of UPDATE , INSERT AND DELETE actions.
I wonder if so many indexes might decrease the performance of complicated SELECT query?

Comment: I do not know the details for Oracle, but having more indexes means more different plans are possible, and the query optimizer has to compare them and pick the "best" one - if there are too many of them, it may need to prune some of them early to keep the planning time and memory under control so maybe the actual best plan might be skipped because of some pruning heuristic, and sometimes it has to *sample* the data in the index. And each additional index probably at least doubles the number of possible plans (use vs not-use), thats a big number of combinations for 3*80 indexes.

Comment: too many indexs=potentially harm insert, update, delete. too less indexes=potentially harms SELECTs.  Possible duplicates [How many database indexes is too many?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141232/how-many-database-indexes-is-too-many) and [Can Indices actually decrease SELECT performance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11361510/can-indices-actually-decrease-select-performance)

Comment: Too many indexes can cause problems with exec plan stability. .i.e. you may face problems, when Oracle suddenly "change exec plan without warning". It can also be sign, that there were performance problems in the past and somebody tried to fix them, without knowing what exactly is going on.

Comment: I think the more likely culprit is the query in the view definition itself as well as how the view is accessed.  I would start with tuning the select in the view first before looking into indexing issues.

Answer (score 0):

For me too many indexes means that it is more expensive to insert, update, or delete rows. Because, if the indexes are of any use they need to be maintained. Find all of the indexes with columns that you either don't query, or don't query very often and drop them. Find all of the indexes where the columns are the same, but in a different order drop all but one version of those. For example a good index would start with low cardinality and get more specific. For example country, state, city, zip code. Another good method would be that if you search by date and other fields lead with the date column to eliminate the largest number of rows first, then choose the values where the other fields match. Try to get the number of indexes down to less than 10 per table.

Although the number of indexes that are useful depends on whether this is OLTP, DSS or data warehouse.

Answer (score 0):

As the comment by [JSapkota](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/68931/jsapkota) says, the [answer exists on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11361670/1227152):

> *Can Indices actually decrease SELECT performance?*
>
> Yes, albeit very slightly - so slightly that it would be justified to also answer "No".
>
> If you have an index which might be considered for a query, but is not useable, the optimizer will waste a short time pondering whether and how to use it (in rare cases with REALLY complicated indexes and views, and more frequently when index performance hints are wrong, you might end up choosing a suboptimal query plan).

The "short time" in the quote above will usually be in the range of microseconds, few milliseconds at worst.

On the other hand:

> Too many indexes can cause problems with exec plan stability. .i.e. you may face problems, when Oracle suddenly "change exec plan without warning". It can also be sign, that there were performance problems in the past and somebody tried to fix them, without knowing what exactly is going on. *[ibre5041](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/18697/ibre5041)*

So may be you should spend some time [looking for unused indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65234222/how-to-find-and-delete-unused-indexes-in-oracle).